# Populating an array defined in a structure

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to populate an array of vertices with float coordinates but its not going well. I define multiple Structures as shown below:

```
typedef struct _Polyg 
{
   float *verts;
   int nverts;
} Polyg;

typedef struct _Layer 
{
   // array of polygons
   Polyg *polys;
   int npolys;
} Layer;
```

So I have Layers, which consist of polygons which consist of vertices essentially. I then attempt to populate the data structure arrays as following:

```
void loadLayers(Layer *layers) 
{
    // takes an array of layers and fills them with data
    layers[0].npolys = 2;
    layers[0].polys[0].nverts = 8;
    layers[0].polys[0].verts = {     //ERROR IS HERE
    100.0f, 134.0f, 0.0f,
    100.0f, 115.0f, 0.0f,
    119.0f, 98.0f, 0.0f,
    119.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    7.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    3.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f,
    3.0f, 130.0f, 0.0f,
    7.0f, 134.0f, 0.0f, };
}
```

So in this exmaplen I'm attempting to populate the first polygon of the first layer with the vertex coordinates (X, Y, Z). However I am getting errors:

> Expected an Expression

and

> C2059 - syntax error: '{'

on the line I commented above.

Really lost with what's going wrong here.

Comment: OT: don't `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: You seem to have quite a few misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: Pointer and array are two separate things. Also you should really prefer using `std::vector` and `std::array` (which avoids many common errors and confusion)

Comment: `float verts[]` - array of floats, `float *verts` - pointer to float verts

Answer (score 0):

With the line: `layers[0].polys[0].verts = {` you're trying to do [initializer-list assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to a `float*` which is only allowed if:

> An assignment expression, where list-initialization initializes the parameter of the overloaded `operator=`

`float*` is a built in type, thus it's built in assignment operator will only take a `float*`. Meaning that you cannot assign an `initializer_list<float>` to a `float*`.

---

Instead consider `vector<float>` which *does* have the builtin `operator= (initializer_list<float>)` defined: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

Additionally consider elimination of the `_Polyg` and `_Layer` structs all together, in favor of `vector`s.